# Could not access to flyway API document or jars

Tags: flyway

Just a few day before, I can download jars from https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/api/

And access the API docs in https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway

Now these link just forward to https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/

Google search also return the old link.
I ask on the red-gate forum and there are no feedback.
Do you know how to access the jars and the API docs now?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Flyway API docs have moved [here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/api-java-184127629.html).
And the Javadocs linked from [here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/api-javadoc-184127636.html).

I will find out whether redirects can be set up for the links you specified - thanks!